# determine List type in C#

Tags: .net-3.5

Is there any way using reflection in C# 3.5 to determine if type of an object `List<MyObject>`?
For example here:

```
Type type = customerList.GetType();

//what should I do with type here to determine if customerList is List<Customer> ?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add to Lucas's response, you'll probably want to be a little defensive by making sure that you do in fact have `List<something>`:

```
Type type = customerList.GetType();
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
else
    // it's not a list at all
```

**Edit:** The above code says, 'what kind of list is it?'. To answer 'is this a `List<MyObject>?`', use the `is` operator as normal:

```
isListOfMyObject = customerList is List<MyObject>
```

Or, if all you have is a `Type`:

```
isListOfMyObject = typeof<List<MyObject>>.IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type[] typeParameters = type.GetGenericArguments();
if( typeParameters.Contains( typeof(Customer) ) )
{
    // do whatever
}
```